# How to create the outer polygon from an array of objects close from each other in QGIS

Tags: qgis, outline

So, I got a polygon layer with lots of 2.3x66m panels (6300) distributed in small groups in random distributions and I need to get the polygon of the enclosing area around those specific objects like this:

[image]

I tried "dissolve" but as every panel is a single feature it returns the same layer. Any idea of a better way to do this than manually draw them?

Comment: You might try buffering your polygons with a small buffer just large enough to fill those small gaps, then run a negative buffer of the same size on the result.